# Filter sales/order collection according to country

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, order-collection

I would like to filter out my home country (GB or United Kingdom) from the following sales/order collection. How can this be done?

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()            
        ->addFieldToSelect('entity_id')
        ->addFieldToFilter('status', 'complete')
        ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')
            ->setPageSize(40); // Last 40 Orders
```

Comment: the order collection is having data about customers' orders. Then against these, we have customers' address, customer shipping address. So your question leaves a lot of space for ambiguity: do you mind to remove any ambiguity and I'll give it a go, thanks

Comment: Wanted to filter out any UK orders at the query level
Have tried
->joinAttribute('shipping_country', 'order_address/country_id', 'shipping_address_id', null, 'left')
->addAttributeToFilter('shipping_country', array('neq' => 'UK'));
But was struggling to get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the query below may do the trick for you:

```
 /** @var Mage_Core_Model_Resource $resource
*/
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToSelect('entity_id')
                ->addFieldToFilter('status', 'complete')
                ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')
                ->setPageSize(40); // Last 40 Orders

$orders->join('order_address',
                'main_table.entity_id=order_address.parent_id',
                ['address_type', 'country_id']);
$orders->addAttributeToFilter('order_address.address_type', 'shipping');
$orders->addAttributeToFilter('order_address.country_id', 'GB');
```

Comment: Did this resolve your issue @hejhog

Comment: Thanks for your answer - perfect. Just for reference I wanted non-GB therefore changed to $orders->addAttributeToFilter('order_address.country_id', array('neq' => 'GB'));

Comment: thanks for the update, appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you can get the `Shipping address` and `Customer data` from the Order collection. from that, you can easily get the country name/id.

Because you can not directly filter the `sales/order` collection by country. you need to build your custom code for that.

Here is the code you can use to get the order shipping address/ billing address details

```
$incrementid ="100000004";
$_order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($incrementid);

OR

$order_id ="4";
$_order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);

$_shippingAddress = $_order->getShippingAddress();
echo $_shippingAddress->getCountry_id();
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks but I need to filter out the UK orders at the collection. See comment above.